# What is the value for SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT?

Tags: odbc, constants

Boy it's annoying when you run into a problem where your code base doesn't have the latest constants and there is something you want to run and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713605%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  just tells you to use SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT.

Does anyone know the value behind this constant?

Please let me know if there is a repository of the values of these constants, sometimes MSDN has them - especially for error codes, but most of the stuff I see on this particular MSDN article isn't in our aged ODBC interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it 113?

(Googled * #define SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT *)

Comment: Good idea! const SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT shows the same thing, I wouldn't have thought of that because I usually put my constants in a block (and I'm a delphi programmer).

Comment: Good point :) *const* is better programming practice than #define anyway.